# When redirecting to /dev/udp, how do you force a packet with newlines to be a single packet?

Tags: bash, shell, udp, ipv4

The simplest example is the following:

```
echo -e "\n\n\n" > /dev/udp/192.168.45.45/9875
```

Looking at this with tcpdump, it's actually sending 4 packets. If I needed to send a single packet consisting of hex (payload) 0a0a0a, is that possible using the /dev/udp device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and it appears to send just a single packet of four (=trailing newline included) characters:

```
echo -e "\n\n\n" >/tmp/foo
cat /tmp/foo > /dev/udp/10.211.55.9/42000
```

The problem appears to be in echo instead of /dev/udp.

Hope this helps.
Hannu

Comment: Not exactly elegant, but it helps. Thank you for the answer, I didn't even think to check that.

Comment: I think the problem is line-buffered output.

Answer (score 3):

You can eliminate the final `\n` with `-n` option:

```
echo -n -e "\n\n\n" > /dev/udp/192.168.45.45/9875
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Hannu's answer and @Damon's comment, I found a couple other ways you can do this:

```bash
# stdbuf disables buffering with the -o0 option
stdbuf -o0 echo -e "\n\n\n" > /dev/udp/192.168.45.45/9875
# use a here doc with cat to avoid needing a temporary document
cat > /dev/udp/192.168.45.45/9875 <<EOF


EOF
#or echo through cat
echo -e "\n\n\n" | cat > /dev/udp/192.168.45.45/9875
```